# How to enable jsp-tags autocompletion in NetBeans within NetBeans Maven projects?

Tags: maven, netbeans, autocomplete, jsp-tags, opencms

Using NetBeans 7.1.2.

When editing pages with NetBeans as per the procedure explained below, the IDE offers only autocompletion for `<jsp:...>` tags:

[image]

This is how I have created the NetBeans project and the jsp (though it isn't archetype specific, nor the issue has anything to do with opencms): I have created a maven project with the [OpenCms-Module archetype](http://bp-cms-commons.sourceforge.net/m2site/infonova/archetypes/opencms-module-archetype/1.0.1/)

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://bp-cms-commons.sourceforge.net/m2repo
```

The archetype creates a maven project with **jar** packaging.

After that, I have added a jsp under `src/main/opencms/modules/blahblah/templates`.

And then I have added the `taglibs.standard` dependency to the project, to try to provide NetBeans with the corresponding tlds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours trying to get this working, I found [this reported and closed bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=179584) that hinted me into the right direction:

1. <strike>Added `src/main/webapp` directory</strike> **Edit 1**: There is autocompletion *only* for `jstl` tags if the files are inside `src/main/webapp`. **Workaround in linux** (not sure if windows links will work): Create a symlink:

   - `ln -s opencms/ src/main/webapp` from the project root folder
2. Change maven project packaging to `war` (`Project properties -> General -> Packaging`)
   (*Notice that neither the `@taglib` directive nor the `taglibs.standard` dependency are necessary.*)

   If the `Web Pages` entry does not appear under your project (in the projects view), you may need to restart NetBeans. Now you'll have full autocompletion (only) under `src/main/webapp`! :-)

[image: Autocompletion fixed]

**Edit 2**

Unfortunately, if under version control, NetBeans sees the symlink as a new directory, and all files under it, as new files :-( This is very inconvenient, because to access the IDE integrated version control functionality, you still need to open the original resource.

Comment: I leave the question open, as I still don't have autocompletion for other taglibs! :-(

Comment: Uhmmm... I have found that the autocompletion works if the file is placed under src/main/webapp! (Suggested in [one of the comments](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=179584#c3) of the bug mentioned in the answer.)

Comment: I have [reopened the bug](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=179584#c13).